# Load testing - dynamic ajax data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, load-testing

using VS2012 and load testing.
I have a page which has 2 drop down lists.

when dropdownlist1 gets changed, an ajax call is made to get the list for dropdownlist2.

in a load/web test - how would I be able to get the values rather than having it hardcoded already by default in the webtest/loadtest? so whatever data is coming back from the initial values from dropdownlist1, the call is made to get the items for dropdownlist2 for the value selected from dropdownlist1?

is this possible?

currently, the webtest records the values I have chosen from the web test recorder. but this wouldn't quite be an accurate webtest where the values are already stored in the test and is submitting them.